# How can I use multiple HTTP methods in simple_form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I have a view like this:

```
= simple_form_for @fixed_number, url: polymorphic_path([:manage, @numberable, :fixed_number]), method: :put do |f|
  = f.input :number
  = f.submit 'Ok', class: "btn btn-success"
  = f.button :button, "Delete", class: "btn btn-danger", method: :delete
```

Obviously I want that Delete button to send the DELETE method. It doesn't work - it uses the PUT specified for the whole form.  Can I have one form that changes method for a particular button?

Comment: If the answer worked for you, you may mark it as "Correct".

Comment: @DaniSpringer apparently I have to wait a couple of days before that is permitted.

Comment: Makes sense! All the best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. I don't know if it's the best one. In particular it relies on UJS and CSS. I replaced the delete button with a styled link:

```
  = link_to "Delete", f.options[:url], method: :delete, class: "btn btn-danger"
```